# how to add 1 year in selected date value in php

Tags: php

I am trying to add 1 year in selected date but I cannot get the output.

This is what I tried so far:

I am getting date from datepicker in textbox and store it in variable like the following:

```
$sdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['amc_date']);
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
$edate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($sdate)));
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Modify the date before you escape it. In fact, use parameterized queries instead of manually escaping strings.

Comment: show us the output of `var_dump($sdate );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` object for this.

```
// $sdate = '2018-04-02'
$sdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['amc_date']);
$dateTime = new \DateTime($sdate);
$resultDate = $dateTime->modify('+1 year')->format('d/m/Y');
// $resultDate = '02/04/2019'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$futureDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 year'));

$futureDate is one year from now!

$futureDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 year',strtotime($startDate)));

$futureDate is one year from $startDate!
```